# fileprovider external-files-path share empty

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I see very codes and examples but my App doesn't work correctly yet,
i want share my images on 
 `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ir.esfandune.mohsen/files/Download/` folders like
 `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ir.esfandune.mohsen/files/Download/cnt_imags/images/n1/n1 (18).jpg` , i defin a provider in manifest:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and XML:

[image]

and my code is :

```
 File file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File f = new File(file.getPath() + File.separator + "cnt_imags" + File.separator);
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ReadActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID ,fA); .....
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        intent.setType("image/png");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

but when send to other apps, don't share anythings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a `Uri`, then you did nothing with it. For `ACTION_SEND`, you attach the `Uri` as the `EXTRA_STREAM` extra.

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) for more.